# If $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{3x^2-2x^3}$, and $x_0\in (0,1)$ let $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. Show $x_n$ coverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

Let $f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R,$ $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{3x^2-2x^3}$ and $I_n = \int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx.$ $x_{0}\in (0,1), x_{n+1}=f(x_{n}), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Show that $(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent and calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty }x_{n}$

Also, if you could generally describe this type of exercise and its solution, I would appreciate it (as I can't find something similar in my 12th grade manual).

PS: I don't know if the integral is necessary to determine the answers (this is the 3rd part of the exercise).

Comment: Title is not the same as first line of question. The title should summarize, and the question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence converges because$$(\forall x\in(0,1)):1>f(x)>x.$$Therefore, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an increasing sequence bounded above by $1$ and so it is convergent.

The previous inequalities can be proved as follows:\begin{align*}f(x)>x&\iff3x^2-2x^3>x^3\\&\iff3x^3>3x^3\\&\iff1>x\end{align*}and$$1>f(x)\iff1>3x^2-2x^3$$and, if we define $g(x)=3x^2-2x^3$, then $g'(x)=6x(1-x)\geqslant0$ if $x\in(0,1)$. Since $g(1)=1$, $g(x)<1$ when $x\in(0,1)$.